# Django keeps redirecting to https in local environment

Tags: django, http, https

I'm trying to run my project in django in local without using https. I have added the following to the settings I'm using:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'http'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') (commented)
```

I'm running the serve with the following command: `python3 manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000`. If I browse to `0.0.0.0:8000`, it works (it uses http). Nonetheless, if I use `localhost:8000` then it always redirects to https and the following error appears:

[image]

I do not know if it helps, but I'm using django 1.11 version inside a docker container.

Comment: I presume the issue is with the browser's cache. Do you have the same issue while accessing the same URL from an incognito mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to `True` once, and accessed `localhost` from browser, redirection happens and its stored in cache. Even if you revert `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to `False`, you will observe the redirection. You can either check in incognito mode or clear browser cache.